# My Java Program can't connect to the MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql

Yesterday I spent several hours trying to solve this problem.
When I try to connect to MySQL server from my Java program I get the `CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`.
I have encountered several questions on Stackoverflow with similar problems but none of the solutions that were provided in the answers worked for me. For instance I have read an answer which advises to replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" or with my private IP address in the `Driver.getConnection` method, but that didn't solve the problem.I have read an answer which suggested that it should be checked whether the server is running. So, I typed `sudo service mysql status` and I saw that the server was active and operational. I have read an answer telling me to add the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` so I did that but that didn't help either.

Here is my Java code

```
package com.mainpackage;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?user=userName&passwword=userPassword");
    }
}
```

Here is the entire message from the terminal that I have received:

```
java -classpath .:/home/javaUtil/MySQL/mysql-connector.jar com/mainpackage/Main

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at com.mainpackage.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
    ... 9 more
```

Edit: I don't have big enough reputation to respond in the comment, so I will add additional information here. I am able to connect to the server from terminal by writting `mysql -u username -p`. Everything works fine then.

Comment: Is your database *definitely* listening on port 3306? Have you verified that with (for example) netstat?

Comment: I would start with `mysql -u userName -puserPassword db1` at the command line on that server to make sure it works

Comment: In your command `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?user=userName&passwword=userPassword` the word `password` is misspelled, can that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem and I want to share the solution in case someone else faces the same problem. As Jon Skeet suggested in his comment, the server, for whatever reason, wasn't listening on port 3306.
I confirmed this by logging into the mysql server via terminal (`mysql -u root -p`) and then I wrote 
`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` 
It said that port was 0 instead of 3306. Here is how I changed the port. 
I went to  `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` 
then I edited the file which is named `mysqld.cnf`. 
On my PC, that file was a read-only file, so I needed to first change the permissions. 
I wrote
`sudo chmod +rw mysqld.cnf` in the terminal while I was in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` directory. 
After that, I edited the file by typing `sudo gedit mysqld.cnf`
in the terminal. 
In the file, I added
`port = 3306` in a new line, below [mysqd], so that it looks like this

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
```

I restarted the mysql server by writting `sudo service mysql restart` in terminal.

Just as a quick note, if you want to run the server with skip-grant-tables option, this  is where you add skip-grant-tables, you add it on the same place that I added port = 3306.